# What kind of desserts are these?

Tags: katakana

My "katakana-go" is a bit rusty. I'm pretty sure the bottom one is a raisin and buttercream cake (or something like that) but not sure about the top. I'm assuming it's a transliteration of a foreign dessert but don't know what it is.
[image]

Comment: [We don't do translations.](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/799/1628)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The names of these products are making use of 飾りフランス語 to give a French touch to them, but suggesting they are related to any existing foreign desserts remains to be seen...

ブランチュール is probably made of ブラン (*blanc*) and チュール (*tulle*). For the first part, English *bran* can certainly be discarded in favor of French *blanc* (*white*) since it contains *milk chocolate* (ミルクチョコレート).

ラングドシャクッキー can be parsed as ラングドシャ (*langue-de-chat*), which is a very thin finger-shaped crisp biscuit or piece of chocolate, and クッキー (*cookie*)... See: [cat's tongue cookie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_tongue).

ガトーレーズン is made of ガトー (*gâteau*), a rich cake, and レーズン (*raisin*), partially dried grape.

EDIT: Alternatively, ブラン could be French *brun* (*brown*), which would match the packaging color then...